# Google script: adapting script to apply to multiple sheets, quick correction

Tags: google-sheets

I trying to add additional lines so that this timestamp script works for multiple tabs in my sheet.

The timestamp works if i enter data into col E on the sheet 'Sanshiro'. 
However it nothing happens if entered into Col E on any of the other specified sheets. 
Does something need changing?

Here is the sheet I am trying to use it with. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K8QhVKWSsvHTFKDHNv3ySb5bcaU9I7tczIZvIkegbw0/edit#gid=1582815105

Thanks in advance!!

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sanshiro" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
    if( s.getName() == "Josh" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
      if( s.getName() == "Suil" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the timestamp works on the 'Sanshiro' sheet but not on the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem but thanks for looking anyway!
I thought I'd post for those also new to scripting.

I didn't close each section properly with enough }
So I needed two } after each section for each sheet.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sanshiro" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }    }
    if( s.getName() == "Josh" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }  }
      if( s.getName() == "Suil" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }  }
        if( s.getName() == "Yujiro" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }  }
          if( s.getName() == "Martin" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -4);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
              }
            }
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why you have to repeat all those blocks of identical code over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your script can be simplified to:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheets = ["Sanshiro", "Josh", "Suil", "Yujiro", "Martin"];
if (sheets.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName()) === -1 || e.range.columnStart !== 5) return;
e.range.offset(0, -4)
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```

Explanation:

- all the sheet names you want the script to work on are in the array 'sheets'
- the if-statemenet checks if the name of the currently edited sheet (e.source.getActiveSheet.getName) is to be found in the array 'sheets'. If it is not indexOf() will return -1 in which case we exit the script.
- second part of the if-statement checks if the edited column is column 5 and exits if that is not the case.
- if indeed both conditions are met, a timestamp is set in col A of the edited sheet (col 5 --> offset with 0 rows and -4 columns = col 1 (A) of the same row).

Hope that helps ?

Comment: Actually I'm having some trouble with this. 

I get