# How to loop static timestamp script Google sheets to all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just over my head with the loop, I have tried few variations I've found from here but I can't get anything to work. And now I'm just confused what part I took from where and starting from scratch again.

This is what I want, but for all year/12 sheets

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if( s.getName() == "jan22" ) { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, -3);
    if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
    nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
    }
}
```

I have tried the
var sheets = ["feb22", "mar22", "apr22", "may22", "jun22", "jul22", "aug22", "sep22", "oct22", "nov22", "dec22" ];

I found from here [Google script: adapting script to apply to multiple sheets, quick correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977118/google-script-adapting-script-to-apply-to-multiple-sheets-quick-correction)

I also tried what I found from here [Google Sheets Script: How to run function on loop over all sheets in workbook and onOpen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57259691/google-sheets-script-how-to-run-function-on-loop-over-all-sheets-in-workbook-an)
and here
[Copy row to another sheet via for loop google sheets script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079616/copy-row-to-another-sheet-via-for-loop-google-sheets-script)

But I started getting errors that even ss.getsheets is not correct term. I think I just cannot remove the unrelated commands/add the relevant ones. (This is 3rd day in my life I've even known about Apps Script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd want the function to all sheets in the spreadsheet, you can remove the first if-statement.

Try

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, -3);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you so much, so simple! I fought with this problem for hours. It still doesn't work for the original files, but perhaps I will create new ones for next year from scratch. The original ones have a lot of merged cells/columns I think that is the reason